# MS Access query incorrectly summing totals

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a set of queries that I have been unable to successfully run because of a table's relationship. This problem has plagued me for a while now and I've yet to solve it. I've seen similar problems but am unable to implement their solutions for my situation.

I believe this is related to the type of join I am using in my tables. I have tried changing the join in the query but it won't work because the SQL joins are ambiguous at that point and the query won't run. Correcting the join and/or using subqueries is probably the solution I need, however I'm unable to implement it correctly.

This fist query is comprised of five tables. Its purpose is to provide YTD total giving for anyone who's given in `ReportYear` along with a breakdown by month (I'm not listing all columns to save space here):

```
tblPartner
    IDPartner (Primary Key) 
    Other demographic info

tblDonation
    ID (Primary Key)
    IDPartner
    Amount
    Other financial info (giving method, designation, etc)

tblChildSponsorship
    ID (Primary Key)
    IDPartner
    Other sponsorship info (level, giving frequency, etc)

tblARBType (this is for tacking online giving, not really important for
            the query but it is nice to have the info displayed)

tblReportParameters (this query holds user input information to specify
    ReportYear       certain parameters of the query like date ranges or
                     donation amounts)
```

`tblPartner` has a one to many relationship with both `tblDonation` and `tblChildSponsorship`. The related fields are `IDPartner` in all three tables.

Here is my SQL from Access:

```
SELECT 
    tblPartner.IDPartner, 
    IIf([tblPartner.PartnerLastName]="",  tblpartner.PartnerFirstName],[tblPartner.PartnerFirstName] & " " & [tblPartner.PartnerLastName]) AS Partner,
    tblPartner.Organization, IIf([tblARBType.ARBType]="N/A","Check",[tblARBType.ARBType]) AS ARB,
    IIf([Premium]=True,"Premium","Standard") AS SponsorLevel,
    tblPartner.Active,
    tblReportParameters.ReportYear, 
    Year([DateGiven]) AS YYYY,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=1,[Amount],0)) AS Jan,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=2,[Amount],0)) AS Feb,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=3,[Amount],0)) AS Mar,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=4,[Amount],0)) AS Apr,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=5,[Amount],0)) AS May,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=6,[Amount],0)) AS Jun,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=7,[Amount],0)) AS Jul,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=8,[Amount],0)) AS Aug,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=9,[Amount],0)) AS Sep,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=10,[Amount],0)) AS Oct,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=11,[Amount],0)) AS Nov,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=12,[Amount],0)) AS [Dec],
    Sum(IIf(Year([DateGiven]),[Amount],0)) AS YTD
FROM
    tblReportParameters, 
    (
      (
       tblARBType INNER JOIN tblPartner ON tblARBType.ID = tblPartner.ARBType
      ) 
      INNER JOIN tblChildSponsorship ON tblPartner.IDPartner = tblChildSponsorship.IDPartner
    )
    INNER JOIN tblDonation ON tblPartner.IDPartner = tblDonation.IDPartner
GROUP BY tblPartner.IDPartner, 
  IIf([tblPartner.PartnerLastName]="",[tblpartner.PartnerFirstName],[tblPartner.PartnerFirstName] & " " & [tblPartner.PartnerLastName]),
  tblPartner.Organization, 
  IIf([tblARBType.ARBType]="N/A","Check",[tblARBType.ARBType]),
  IIf([Premium]=True,"Premium","Standard"), 
  tblPartner.Active, 
  tblReportParameters.ReportYear,
  Year([DateGiven])
HAVING 
    (((Year([DateGiven]))=[ReportYear]));
```

I am so sorry for that wall of text query.

If I remove `tblChildSponsorship` from the query it returns the correctly summed amounts. Once I add that query in I start getting duplicated totals. Within our system it is possible for a partner to sponsor more than one child, thus I think that is where the error is happening due to join type. The erroneous amounts follow a general pattern of the sum total being multiplied by the number of children sponsored.

I have looked at using `DISTINCT` AND `DISTINCTROW` but neither of those changed anything which has further led me to the assumption that my joins are bad.

As mentioned I've tried various subqueries to resolve this issue but I end of having the same results and problems when attempting to change the join types.

I realize the `tblChildSponorship` is only being used for one field, however my second query has some minor differences but uses the same three main tables with the same relationship structure. If a solution can be determined for one it will most definitely solve the other. I hope I've provided enough information but if there is anything else you need please let me know.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are not adequately joining tblChildSponsorship which is why you get duplicated totals. Check that the key fields for that table are correctly joined.

Comment: @DaveRlz the PK field of `tblPartner` is `IDPartner` and is joined to the corresponding `IDPartner` fields in the other two tables. Those fields are not PKs in the other two tables as they can have multiple entries in the donation and sponsorship tables.

Comment: Having spent more time looking at your question I've realised I am not sure what you are trying to do. DISTINCT won't work because each row you think is actually a duplicate will have a different child sponsorship. I suspect your GROUP BY is the culprit, could you explain more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This query's purpose is to show YTD partner giving. I also want it to break down the giving my month. This allows us to quickly look at giving histories to see when partner's fell off, when they started, who is consistent, etc. `tblChildSponsorship` is in the query solely to show the sponsorship level, which is Premium or Standard. Since these amounts vary by level it allows us to put the donation amounts in context. The other query uses the same structure but shows Partner giving YTD based on sponsored child so a much smaller list of partners is returned in that query.

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting the Donations and Sponsorship into separate aggregation queries and then joining them into one. Because the Partner and Child Sponsorship share a one-to-many relationship, you do not want to join and then aggregate in one process or each combination of joined records (i.e., multiple Partner IDs) will be included. So, simply aggregate each set separately at Partner level and then join both together at end.

**Partner-Donation Aggregate Query** *(similar to above without tblChildSponsorship join)*

```
SELECT tblPartner.IDPartner, 
    IIf([tblPartner.PartnerLastName]='', tblpartner.PartnerFirstName],
        [tblPartner.PartnerFirstName] & ' ' & [tblPartner.PartnerLastName]) AS Partner,
    tblPartner.Organization, 
    IIf([tblARBType.ARBType]='N/A','Check',[tblARBType.ARBType]) AS ARB,
    tblPartner.Active,
    tblReportParameters.ReportYear, 
    Year([DateGiven]) AS YYYY,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=1,[Amount],0)) AS Jan,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=2,[Amount],0)) AS Feb,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=3,[Amount],0)) AS Mar,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=4,[Amount],0)) AS Apr,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=5,[Amount],0)) AS May,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=6,[Amount],0)) AS Jun,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=7,[Amount],0)) AS Jul,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=8,[Amount],0)) AS Aug,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=9,[Amount],0)) AS Sep,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=10,[Amount],0)) AS Oct,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=11,[Amount],0)) AS Nov,
    Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=12,[Amount],0)) AS [Dec],
    Sum(IIf(Year([DateGiven]),[Amount],0)) AS YTD
FROM tblReportParameters, 
    (tblARBType INNER JOIN tblPartner ON tblARBType.ID = tblPartner.ARBType) 
    INNER JOIN tblDonation ON tblPartner.IDPartner = tblDonation.IDPartner
GROUP BY tblPartner.IDPartner, 
  IIf([tblPartner.PartnerLastName]='', [tblpartner.PartnerFirstName],
      [tblPartner.PartnerFirstName] & ' ' & [tblPartner.PartnerLastName]),
  tblPartner.Organization, 
  IIf([tblARBType.ARBType]='N/A','Check',[tblARBType.ARBType]),
  tblPartner.Active, 
  tblReportParameters.ReportYear,
  Year([DateGiven])
HAVING (((Year([DateGiven]))=[ReportYear]));
```

**Sponsorship Aggregate Query** *(taking latest entry of `[Premium]`)*

```
SELECT IDPartner, Last(IIf([Premium]=True,'Premium','Standard')) AS SponsorLevel,
FROM tblChildSponsorship
GROUP BY IDPartner;
```

**Final Join Query**

```
SELECT d.IDPartner, d.Partner, d.Organization, d.ARB, d.Active, d.ReportYear, d.YYYY
       d.Jan, d.Feb, d.Mar, d.Apr, d.May, d.Jun, 
       d.Jul, d.Aug, d.Sep, d.Oct, d.Nov, d.Dec, d.YTD,
       s.SponsorLevel           
FROM DonationsAgg d
INNER JOIN SponsorshipAgg s
ON d.IDPartner = s.IDPartner
```

By the way, it is conceivable to handle all above queries into one query using derived tables (nested select statements in `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses). But MS Access allows for stored queries which may facilitate maintainability of code sources.

```
SELECT DonationsAgg.IDPartner, DonationsAgg.Partner, 
       DonationsAgg.Organization, DonationsAgg.ARB, DonationsAgg.Active, 
       DonationsAgg.ReportYear, DonationsAgg.YYYY
       DonationsAgg.Jan, DonationsAgg.Feb, DonationsAgg.Mar, 
       DonationsAgg.Apr, DonationsAgg.May, DonationsAgg.Jun, 
       DonationsAgg.Jul, DonationsAgg.Aug, DonationsAgg.Sep,
       DonationsAgg.Oct, DonationsAgg.Nov, DonationsAgg.Dec,
       DonationsAgg.YTD, SponsorshipAgg.SponsorLevel
FROM
  (...Partner-Donation Aggregate Query...) As DonationsAgg
INNER JOIN
  (...Sponsorship Aggregate Query...) As SponsorshipAgg
ON DonationsAgg.IDPartner = SponsorshipAgg.IDPartner
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not the best option but you can devide sum by child count like so:

```
SELECT 
    ..
    ,Sum(IIf(Month([DateGiven])=1,[Amount],0)) / count(distinct tblChildSponsorship.ID) AS Jan,
    ..
```